# How can this be done with MySQL or do I need to write a php script

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database news under which there's a table called links. One of the colum is called link_title and it will have content like this without quotes "neil-degrasse-tyson-why-you-will-levitate". There are about 40,000 rows in that table.

I have a txt file called topUrls.txt from Google analytics which shows the top visited 1500 URLs on my site. One line, one URL. And the URLs have been cleaned to match the content of link_title in the DB.

Can someone guide me on a mysql script to basically clean the links table of all rows that do not have a link_title which matches one of the 1500 URLs in the text file. Or do I need to program this in php or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load topUrls.txt into a table.  Let's call it topUrls and call the single column of that table Url.  Then match link_title to topUrls and delete on a mis-match

```
delete links
where link_title not in (
    select Url from topUrls)
```

This only works if the content of the Google file *exactly* matches the existing database rows.  Otherwise you will have to had a further `WHERE` clause to the sub-select withsome string manipulation in it.